# How to force jquery get to stop ignoring decimal point values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

im creating gauges using justgauge. I'm using jquery get method and the data from database, but it only gives me integer number, while i expect floating point value.

```
//PHP code to get the value from database
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$connect = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");
$query = "SELECT wilgotnosc FROM Pomiary ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);       
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);                         
echo $array[0]; //of course here i got the floating point value
?>
```

Jquery below

```
window.onload = function(){

var g = new JustGage({
id: "gauge",
value: 0,
min: 0,
max: 100,
label: "wilgotność %"
});
    setInterval(function() {
    $.get('api.php', function (newValue) { g.refresh(newValue); });
```

The $.get returning only integer value, how can i get the float value?

Comment: @Xufox adding step causing crash and all the gauges disappearing

Comment: Open your developer tools and go to your network tab.  Inspect the ajax request and verify that the response is a floating point value

Comment: @Taplar i checked in jgauge and there is a function to parse floating point numbers, also from database im getting float values so im sure there is a problem in $.get function.

Comment: So you're avoiding checking the network log to verify the correct result is coming back?  There's "I'm sure", and then there's "The network log explicitly says I'm right/wrong".

Comment: Everything was about setting decimals: true value in justgauge object. problem solved

Comment: So it was returning a float on the ajax, but the config was incorrect on the JustGage?

Comment: @Taplar yes, exactly